# How can I make a cone of light be more realistic?

Tags: light

[image]

Any way I can make the light more realistic? Probably just a bit less opaque.
Probably some tips to reduce noise too, thanks!

The light is a cone with the nodes on the left. Lit up with spot. Made in cycles.

Comment: The opacity is caused by the fact that 93% of your material is an *Emission* node. If you have a spotlight already shining into the volume cone, you shouldn't need an *Emission* node at all.

Comment: You could do something like this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/29586, using an image in the shape of the torch emission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the material created for this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/29586 and use an image to mimic the lens of a torch such as this :

[image: torch lens]

Adjusting the material variables can produce a result like the following :

[image: final]

Blend file attached [image]

To include the material in your own project, simply download the Blend file, open your own project, got to File, Append, select the 'torch' Blend file and navigate to the material ('Material'). Set the two Image nodes to your torch lens image (use the above one if you don't have anything more suitable) and adjust the various variables (the material nodes marked in Cyan) until you get the desired effect.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow... I got lost at "Set the two image nodes..." I got to locate the material all right, but after that, I don't know what to do. After I click "Append from Library," I see nothing happen. If you want to see my project, here it is: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/87677

Comment: @Blenderinator It is a complicated material - and it's dependent on the Object coordinates being aligned with the edge where the image shows on the surface. Create a mesh to act as the 'domain' of the rays (a cube or cuboid will be fine - no need to shape it as a cone) and set the origin as mentioned in the original linked answer. Within the material are two image nodes - set those to the circular image of the torchlight emission; one acts as the image on the surface and the other is spread through the volume as the rays (adjustable via the nodes coloured cyan in the material). Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for realism... then emulate reality. In real life a cone of light is visible because a light source illuminates the particles suspended on the environment. Volume is not emitting and scattering at the same time.Create an environment (or some geometry that works as "domain" for volume scattering) and put the light to shine through it: then the ray of light will be more "realistic". Moreover what makes your scene unrealistic is that there is not even a Light Bulb emitting light on the flashlight.

[image]

[image]

Comment: related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/volumetric-spot-light-with-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/how-can-a-light-cone-volumetric-be-setup-with-cycles/17706#17706

Comment: I tried to do that, but whenever I use volume scatter like what you did, it produces an effect similar to a lot of dust gathered on this rectangle.     https://gyazo.com/d7833befa509d7360ae382ce72e5a6d1

Comment: @Blenderinator See the file linked on the answer. Volume scatter should be connected to the volume socket. Also play with the settings for density. The default value of 1 is usually way too much. Also play with the intensity of the light.