# How can I create a stained glass light effect?

Tags: materials, light, lighting

I'm aiming to re-create this scene I have made in Unreal Engine 4, but I am currently struggling with the stained glass effect seen here: 
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bb8p.jpg

It was constructed in UE4 by essentially stacking three spotlights, each representing a colour channel, and then just aligning them roughly where the stained glass window ought to project that texture.

How could I create a similar effect in Blender?

Comment: Here is the same spot in Blender: http://imgur.com/a/op2n2 For reference

Comment: How about something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/29586 - in particularly the final example https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm886.png.

Comment: That looks like an excellent starting point for the light beam effect, though I'm more interested in the dynamic light texture that is projected onto other surfaces as seen in the UE4 images.

Comment: Are you using cycles or blender internal?

Comment: I'm primarily using Blender Game Engine. As I intend for the final produced version of the scene to include the fly cam (Which I have already implemented) and to use real-time rendering, as a comparison to UE4 for a project.

Answer (score 1):

Add a spot lamp, then go to texture panel, clic on the lightbulb (lamp texture) and add your texture.
I don't use BGE so I couldn't help more with it, but it looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I like your spotlight raycast, it's very clear. Maybe this will help, this is my process for stained glass windows. Test some raycasts through the window 
(I think just white light may raycast the colors or you could try adding an RGB node to that part of the workflow):

Make an alpha transparent image (about 60-80% opaque) in a good image editor, then load it into MindText 2 or Substance B2M.
[image: Stained Glass 1]
Create these 4 or 5 maps: Color (Albedo), Specular, Metallic (optional), Roughness (Glossyness), Normal.

In Blender, apply Principled BSDF nodes as illustrated below:
[image: Stained Glass with light-probe occlusion]

### ... the Light-path node near the end of the workflow will make light-probes invisible to the camera (optional).

***You should end up with something like this:***
[image: Pre-render view - Cycles]

You should probably bake the image and cache the data and test raycasting some light paths.