# Ray effect in cycles

Tags: light

I am trying to make it so that there are "beams" coming out of the top of an object. Here is a crappying drawing: [image: crap drawing]
I have made this so far: 
[image: what i got]

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154

Comment: Also related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/29586