# Realistic Light Reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I have an object that I'm trying to recreate in Blender. It's a bookmark with lights in it, and I'm trying to get it to have the correct light bounces.

[image: bookmark with edges lit just from a side of the glass]

I'm trying to get it to look like this, where the light gets trapped at the edges of the glass and reflected inside. But when I tried making it, the results looked like this.

[image: blender light reflection]

The light doesn't get reflected from the edges of the glass but it escapes. I wonder if there is a way to create it so the light looks like how I want it to.

I used area light to light up the glass. For some reason, I had to put the light source inside the glass. If it were to be a little bit behind the glass, no light would get through even after I made a hole for the glass to insert in the wooden section. I also increased the light intensity for that render because if I didn't, the light wouldn't reach the end of the glass. The max brightness I could set is about 1 W before the red starts overpowering the upper part of the glass in false color mode

[image: false color with lots of red on the glass part]

I'm extremely new to Blender, so please don't use any weird Blender terms.

Comment: you could cheat and give a mix of emission and transparency to these 3 sides, no? as it looks like if the sides emit light

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71385/volumetric-windows-10-logo-effect

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Fake

In edit mode select side faces and assign material with Emision Shader.

[image]

[image]

---

### Realistic

This glass plate consists from three materials:

- front/back side with **Glass Shader**
- bottom side with **Emission Shader**
- top/left/right side with **Glass Shader** but now with **Roughness 1**

[image]

[image]