# Volumetric church window effect

Tags: light, lighting, shadows, volumetrics, effects

I would like to use the attached texture as colored window glass.

I found the following tutorial for this, but I can't follow it pretty early on (*"Assign a material and add the following nodes"*) Is this tutorial still up to date? At the very bottom, a church window was attached in the reply that gives exactly the effect I want to achieve with my file.

What do I have to do for this?

Tutorial: [Volumetric Windows 10 logo effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71385/volumetric-windows-10-logo-effect)

[image: Texture]

Comment: Some things might not be exaclty looking the same in the latest Blender release, but most of the nodes are pretty basic stuff as far as I can see from a quick glance. Why do you get stuck on the first "Assign a material and add the following nodes"? What is your exact problem with this tutorial? Do you need basic help with adding materials or nodes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Volumetric Windows 10 logo effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71385/volumetric-windows-10-logo-effect), result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyRo7.jpg

Comment: Select your Object (Glass) and go to Shader Editor, if none material is set, click "+ New" button (in a middle of top row) and create node tree (start to adding nodes and connect them) according screenshots in tutorial.

Comment: After adding a material as described in the tutorial, I got "Principled BSDF" and "Material Output" once. Should they stay? Do I somehow connect them to the "Texture Coordiante" tree? Unfortunately, there is nothing to see in the pictures. I have made progress up to this point. Now I am trying to add the "Add" node as shown, but I can't find it in the list via Shift+A.

Comment: Does the method described in the instructions make sense at all for larger objects? I have the feeling that with the cube added at the beginning, a larger glass front with a more complex topology is not that easy...

Comment: @brockmann I was able to change the texture to mine in the blend file from the tutorial next door. But the "rays" were still in the shape of the old file and the colours were not mine. What exactly did you change?

Comment: There are 2 image texture nodes within the shader, just swap out the image of both @dnlpck

Comment: Found it. But why is this so much softer and less dominant? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm886.png @brockmann

Comment: Cool, play with the volume density... @dnlpck

Comment: I feel stupid. Where do I find the volume density?

Comment: My fault, it's the 'scatter brightness' right in the middle of the shader, just bump it up.