# Is it possible to reduce light emission to some directions?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, light, lighting, emission

Currently, I have a scene like this - [image: Hallway]
But I'd like the lights to look brighter and see the actual rays, instead the space between green ones darker.
It is possible to change the glow effect in the **compositing tab** with the **glare node**, but in any case, I need more absorption in the gap so that there is more contrast between the dark walls and the bright "*connectors*".

EDIT:
I have been using **Volume Scatter** node, but it doesn't do exactly what I want.

Comment: Do you have reference image to visually understand your goal?

Comment: [video](https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-cyberpunk-square-tunnel-with-neon-lights-19682-large.mp4) - this one is similar, but again, it'd be great if there was more contrast and light rays [like on this picture](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/1e/14/151e145cffb1235334e2bbbc6e60085c.jpg)

Comment: Related - changing the shape of a spotlight https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80007/29586

Comment: Have you considered faking it with volume emission where you want the light instead of scatter? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/29586

Comment: @RichSedman Yes, I have tried all the methods you suggested, but for some reason I can't make the rays visible. I turned off the reflections on the metal and hid all objects except the light, and only in this way could some rays be seen.

Comment: Could you just darken all the surfaces (reflection and diffuse) so they only react to a fraction of the light and then greatly increase the strength of the light? This might reduce the wash-out you’re getting from the surfaces and make the volumetrics more visible.