# How to make light leaks or sun ray?

Tags: light, lighting

I saw this awesome artwork from Mohamed Chahin on instagram. Does anyone know how to make the sun ray?[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/creating-volumetric-lighting-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71385/volumetric-windows-10-logo-effect

Comment: In that case, the "ray" looks to be a mesh, with some transparency and backface culling.  Are you asking how to make the mesh shape?  How to make the shader for the mesh?  Or just the fact that it is a mesh?

Comment: @Nathan I'm asking how to make the shader and I don't know that's a mesh